# How to pass data from a stream server in Python back into the main task?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I've adapted this TCP echo server with streams example to my needs so that I can have multiple clients send data to my device:

```
import asyncio

async def handle_echo(reader, writer):
    data = await reader.read(100)
    message = data.decode()
    addr = writer.get_extra_info('peername')

    print(f"Received {message!r} from {addr!r}")

    print(f"Send: {message!r}")
    writer.write(data)
    await writer.drain()

    print("Close the connection")
    writer.close()

async def main():
    server = await asyncio.start_server(
        handle_echo, '127.0.0.1', 8888)

    addrs = ', '.join(str(sock.getsockname()) for sock in server.sockets)
    print(f'Serving on {addrs}')

    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()

asyncio.run(main())
```

The issue that I'm having is that the clients are essentially producers for another task, but I'm not sure how to be able to consume the data. I've tried declaring and passing asyncio queues into the server and into the callback function, but I've had no luck, as the handle accepts only 2 arguments and I can't declare a queue that's inside the module as it won't be a part of the event loop that's declared in the main task.

Is there a way to do this without going back to sockets?

Answer (score 1):

First: the fact that no asyncio loop is running when module level code is executed does not block the creation of an `asyncio.Queue` instance - just do it, if you want to use asyncio.Queue s at all: but any data structure will work for you, and maybe using a `collections.deque`, which is synchronous, will require less boiler plate when putting/retrieving content for it: since you will already have the data to be put/consumed in the queue, it being synchronous won't make any difference.

Second: if you don't want to have a module-level data structure for that, just create a class wrapping your handler: it will then get the reference to `self`. The same class can wrap  other methods or code that will consume your data - for example, an "awaitable get".

```
import time
from collections import deque
class Handler:
   def __init__(self):
       self.queue = deque()

   async def get(self, timeout=1):
       start = time.time()
       while time.time() - start <= timeout:
          if not self.queue:
              return self.queue.popleft()
          await asyncio.sleep(.0001)

   async def handle_echo(self, reader, writer):
        ...
        self.queue.append(message)
        ...


async def main():
    handler = Handler()
    server = await asyncio.start_server(
        handler.handle_echo, '127.0.0.1', 8888)

    addrs = ', '.join(str(sock.getsockname()) for sock in server.sockets)
    print(f'Serving on {addrs}')

    # pass the handler instance into other async code that will
    # consume the messages:
    ...
    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! For the in-module queue, the issue is that I have a program in which I declare the queue in the main task which then also interacts with 2 I/O-bound tasks (one is using a completely separate library) and also passes the data from those to a consumer task. All of them are logically separate. I can maybe add in an example, but when I tried adding a queue in-module, it didn't pass any data back to the main task. The class idea could work, yeah, I'd just prefer to keep my tasks separate. This is helpful though, thank you!